# Value of K hash functions so that probability of false positive is at most 1/n

Tags: algorithm, probability, bloom-filter, universal-hashing

We have n elements , m=2n and k, where K is the number of hash functions, m being the size of bit array and n the number of elements. What will be the value of k such that the probability of getting a false positive will at most be 1/n

I am working on finding the probability of finding the value of k such that the false positive probability at most is 1/n. What I have done so far is the following.

Pr(bit = 0) = 1-1/m == e^(-kn/m)

then:

Pr(bit = 1) = (1-e^(-kn/m))^k

Now I am stuck at this point and I am unable to get the value of k for which my at most false-positive probability will be 1/n.

Also please let me know if someone thinks what I did so far is an error.

Comment: I think there is a contradiction. If you set m=2n, that means 2 bits per key. If you set that, then you basically have already set the false positive probability (fpp). There is no way to choose k such that the fpp can get lower, let alone become 1/n for larger n.